# Изменение правила деления на 0

Tags: c++, c

Что нужно изменить, или возможно хукнуть (перехватить) для изменения правила деления? В моих задачах при делении числа на 0 должен получаться 0.
Меня интересует именно изменение предписанного алгоритма

Comment: `try` `catch`?.

Comment: Не совсем подойдет. Плюс здесь нискоуровневое исключение, поэтому обычный try не подойдет, а скорее __try.

Comment: а может просто обёртку над делением?

Comment: Написать свою функцию деления и вызывать ее вместо встроенного оператора. Стоит заметить, что если при решении вашей задачи возникает деление на ноль, то в нем наверняка что-то не так.

Comment: VTT, можно пример?
Все верно. Если расстояние равно нулю, значит выходить в результат должен ноль. А исключение просто бесит и ломает приложение

Comment: В результат чего? Вообще, сделайте через if.

Comment: А по какой логике деление на ноль должно давать ноль? Чем меньше делитель, тем больше частное. То есть даже при беззнаковом делении на ноль должна получаться положительная бесконечность.

Comment: Arhad, это индивидуальные уравнения, где 0 это не математический ноль и не имеет те же правила

Comment: Можно попробовать написать обёртку над интами и перегрузить все необходимые операторы.

Comment: Можно хоть пример или ссылку на тему с примером?

Comment: Деление на 0 в С и С++ вызывает неопределенное поведение, а не исключение. "Переписать" нельзя. Хотите по другому - не допускайте деления на ноль.

Comment: В Linux при делении на 0 текущий поток получит сигнал `SIGFPE`. Вы можете его поймать и выполнить переход по `siglongjmp` (или даже, в принципе, изменив контекст (3-й аргумент в обработчике сигнала) повторить операцию с измененным делителем (а на что вы его будете менять?)), но все это слишком вычурно и вряд ли вы это реализуете. Так что, меняйте  свои алгоритмы и структуры данных так, чтобы избежать деления на 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;
class Int_type {
    int k;
public:
    Int_type(int i = 0) : k(i) {}
    Int_type& operator ++() { ++k; return *this; }
    Int_type operator ++(int) { Int_type t; ++(t.k); return t; }
    Int_type& operator =(const int& i) { k = i; return *this; }
    Int_type& operator /=(const int& i) { k = i ? k / i : 0; return *this;}
    operator  int() const { return k; }
};
inline Int_type operator /(const Int_type& n, const int& i)
{
    Int_type t = n;
    t /= i;
    return t;
}
```

Можете использовать обьекты класса вместо обьектов типа int и делить на ноль

```
int main()
{   
    Int_type i;
    i = 19;
    ++i;
    cout << i << endl << i/ 2 << endl << i - 2 <<endl << i * 2  << endl 
         << i/0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: для удобства еще можнл добавить операторы *=, +=, -= .........

Comment: это не ответ на вопрос, вопрос был про изменение поведения стандартных типов, а не про возможность создать свой класс с другим поведением.

Comment: А у вас проблемы с русским языком серьёзные. Чем я себя унижаю то - вы написали как создать свой класс, который будет работать по другому, а не как переопределить стандартное поведение оператора деления для встроенного типа. Я даже не знаю возможно это или нет, но если это невозможно - то надо так и отвечать, что переопределение операций для встроенных типов для си/си++ запрещено.

Comment: Неуместные комментарии ты пишешь. Я написал, что твой код к вопросу отношения прямого не имеет. Создать свой класс с переопределенной операцией деления не одно и то же, что и сделать другим результат деления на 0 везде.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо большое за ответ.
И все же так как ответов не было долгое время, придумал свое решение через фильтр исключений. Должно работать на все int в 32-битном приложении.
Здесь при вызове исключения фильтр проверяет вид операции и заменяет регистр с нулем на единицу. А дальше перепрыгивает на следующую инструкцию

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

LONG WINAPI ExceptionFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExceptionInfo)
{
    cout << "Exception code: 0x" << hex << (int)pExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode << " Exception address: 0x" << (DWORD)pExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Eip << endl;
    if ((int)pExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == 0xc0000094)
    {
        DWORD presentEIP = (DWORD)pExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Eip;
        byte EIPvalue[2];
        EIPvalue[0] = *(byte*)presentEIP;
        EIPvalue[1] = *(byte*)(presentEIP + 0x1);
        if (EIPvalue[0] == 0xF7 && EIPvalue[1] == 0xF9)
        {
            pExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Ecx = 1;
            cout << "Forced ECX to 1 [1]" << endl;
        }
        else if (EIPvalue[0] == 0xF7 && EIPvalue[1] == 0x7D)
        {
            _asm add DWORD PTR SS : [EBP - 8], 1;
            pExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Eip += 3;
            cout << "Forced ECX to 1 [2]" << endl;
        }
        else return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;

        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    }

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int f(int x, int y, int
    z) {
    return 2 + x / (2 / (y - z));
}

int main()
{
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(true, (PVECTORED_EXCEPTION_HANDLER)ExceptionFilter); // Registers our vectored exception handler which is going to catch the exceptions thrown.

    int res = f(2, 3, 3); //F7F9
    cout << "Result: " << dec << res << endl; 

    getchar();

    int zero = 1 * 0;//F77D F8
    int i;
    i = 1 + 5 / zero;
    cout << "Result: " << dec << i << endl;
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А если будет не F7, а допустим 66 F7? Или деление с другой части таблицы, там с FF-расширения? Прийдётся на каждый чих - дорабатывать.

Comment: Исключение - это сначала сигнал ядру, ядро выполняет порядка 200-300 операций перед тем как управление перейдет к ExceptionHandler. А это хорошая потеря в производительности, поэтому - лучше сравнивать.

Comment: Да, совершенно не доработано. Чувствую можно сделать гораздо проще и эффективнее, но пока не знаю как. И похоже никто и париться не хочет. Невозможно и все

Answer (score 0):

Вот так сделал и всё получилось:

```cpp
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

class IntType {
    int k;

public:
    IntType(int i = 0) : k(i) {}
    IntType& operator ++() { ++k; return *this; }
    IntType operator ++(int) { IntType t; ++(t.k); return t; }
    IntType& operator =(const int& i) { k = i; return *this; }
    IntType& operator /=(const int& i) { k = i ? k / i : 0; return *this;}
    operator  int() const { return k; }
};

inline IntType operator /(const IntType& n, const int& i)
{
    IntType t = n;
    t /= i;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Этот ответ практически ничем не отличается от уже принятого ответа.